# Assigning a day, week, and year column in Pandas in one line

Tags: pandas, datetime

I usually have to extract days, weeks and years into separate columns like this:

```
data['Day'] = data.SALESDATE.dt.isocalendar().day
data['Week'] = data.SALESDATE.dt.isocalendar().week
data['Year'] = data.SALESDATE.dt.isocalendar().year
```

But is there a way where I can assign all three in one nice line?

```
data[['Day', 'Week', 'Year']] = ....
``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one line solution use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with rename columns if necessary:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
data = pd.DataFrame({'SALESDATE': rng, 'a': range(10)})  


data = data.join(data.SALESDATE.dt.isocalendar().rename(columns=lambda x: x.title()))

print (data)
   SALESDATE  a  Year  Week  Day
0 2017-04-03  0  2017    14    1
1 2017-04-04  1  2017    14    2
2 2017-04-05  2  2017    14    3
3 2017-04-06  3  2017    14    4
4 2017-04-07  4  2017    14    5
5 2017-04-08  5  2017    14    6
6 2017-04-09  6  2017    14    7
7 2017-04-10  7  2017    15    1
8 2017-04-11  8  2017    15    2
9 2017-04-12  9  2017    15    3
```

Or change order of list and assign:

```
data[['Year', 'Week', 'Day']] = data.SALESDATE.dt.isocalendar()
print (data)
   SALESDATE  a  Year  Week  Day
0 2017-04-03  0  2017    14    1
1 2017-04-04  1  2017    14    2
2 2017-04-05  2  2017    14    3
3 2017-04-06  3  2017    14    4
4 2017-04-07  4  2017    14    5
5 2017-04-08  5  2017    14    6
6 2017-04-09  6  2017    14    7
7 2017-04-10  7  2017    15    1
8 2017-04-11  8  2017    15    2
9 2017-04-12  9  2017    15    3
```

If need changed order of values in list:

```
data[['Day', 'Week', 'Year']] = data.SALESDATE.dt.isocalendar()[['day','week','year']]
print (data)
   SALESDATE  a  Day  Week  Year
0 2017-04-03  0    1    14  2017
1 2017-04-04  1    2    14  2017
2 2017-04-05  2    3    14  2017
3 2017-04-06  3    4    14  2017
4 2017-04-07  4    5    14  2017
5 2017-04-08  5    6    14  2017
6 2017-04-09  6    7    14  2017
7 2017-04-10  7    1    15  2017
8 2017-04-11  8    2    15  2017
9 2017-04-12  9    3    15  2017
```